# Why else does not active in oncreate methode in android?

Tags: java, if-statement

I'm trying to upgrade google play services manually, but always if statement  activated.
I test with two device.In first device that version of google play services smaller than 10  dialog show correctly, but in the second device that google play services has upgraded , the app crashes after execute.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    if (checkPlayServices(ActivityMap.this) == true) {
        dialog.show();
    } else {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);

        shopOnMap();

        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            mLastKnownLocation = savedInstanceState.getParcelable(KEY_LOCATION);
            mCameraPosition = savedInstanceState.getParcelable(KEY_CAMERA_POSITION);
        }

        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .enableAutoManage(this /* FragmentActivity */,
                        this /* OnConnectionFailedListener */)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                .addApi(Places.GEO_DATA_API)
                .addApi(Places.PLACE_DETECTION_API)
                .build();
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();

    }
}


 public boolean checkPlayServices(Activity activity) {
    boolean res= false;
    GoogleApiAvailability apiAvailability = GoogleApiAvailability.getInstance();
    int resultCode = apiAvailability.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(activity);
    if (resultCode != ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(ActivityMap.this);

        builder.setMessage("Do you want update Google play services?")
                .setTitle("Google Play Services"); 

        builder.setPositiveButton("ِDownload", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {

                new DownloadNewVersion().execute();

            }
        });
        builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
        dialog = builder.create();
      res=true;
    }
    return res;

}
```

Comment: When asking questions about code, especially about such context- and semantic-sensitive things as `if` statements and conditions, then always include what language the code is written in, as a tag. Please don't forget it next time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you are handling things wrongly in your code. There's a lot which could be improved but I'll just highlight the important things which I can instantly see in your code.

Like mentioned by @PeterJ, this is the logical error you are making in your code. You are returning `true` in `checkPlayServices()` which should be corrected to return `true` only when your condition `if (resultCode != ConnectionResult.SUCCESS)` is true otherwise it should return `false` so that dialog is not shown in that case.

Now coming to your second concern about crashing. I believe it is because you are calling `super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);` only in your `else` condition.

> Derived class onCreate(bundle) method must call super class implementation of this method. If you do not then an exception will be thrown SuperNotCalledException

To fix this, move this statement to top of your `onCreate()` function and hopefully this will fix the crashing issue caused by it.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is very simply - because you always return the `true` as the return value of this function. The only `return` statement is `return true;`

Comment: WOW,Thanks for answer. How can change the code that if/else condition worked correctly ?

Comment: That's your function how can I know when you need to return false

Comment: I want in the else  return false, but my code not worked too.